# Sencha Touch, how to pass data from list to form?

Tags: sencha-touch

I`m trying to write editable list with sencha touch,

I saw many examples but nothing did not work properly so I decided to build from scratch,

I have a list with items and on item tap my controller run the next code

```
        showDetail: function (list, record) {

    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'vedit',
        title: record.fullDetails(),
        data: record.getData()
    });
```

My "vEdit" screen is an form that should display the current tapped item data

This is the code for the edit form:

```
var form = Ext.define('TM.view.vEdit', {

extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'vedit',

config: {
    title: 'Edit task',
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',

    items: [
       {
           xtype: 'textfield',
           name: 'title',
           label: ''
       },
       {
           xtype: 'textfield',
           name: 'desc',
           label: ''
       }
    ]
}
```

});

I tried to load the data with the next code:

```
var ed = Ext.create('TM.model.mTasks', {
title: 'Ed',
desc: 'ed@sencha.com'
```

});

form.setRecord(ed);

and getting the next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
                return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
            } has no method 'setRecord'
```

NEED YOUR HELP,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not define a field named record in form's config, so you won't get setRecord() method.

To pass on data you may try doing this:

```
form.config.record = ed;
```

and in initialize function of view you can get it like:

```
var taskData = this.config.record;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = Ext.define('TM.view.vEdit', {
```

Man, you need to create new form(), because it's just a type definition.